# how to set html inline css from django

Tags: html, css, django

Hi everyone,
            I am stuck at one point while rendering the data from django views.
I want to use the CSS data produced in views to be used in the template.
I did all I could do, 
          i) inserted the element into the RequestContext, sent it to template
          ii) From here, I tried to insert that CSS style data into div tag

This is my css data in VIEW( they are "left:xx px  top: xx px" positions)

```
coords = {'usa':['usamap.png',['635px','322px'],['592px','381px'],['541px','398px'],['115px','582px']],
           'canada':['canadamap.png',['201px','336px'],['377px','565px'],['420px','600px'],['441px','648px']]
             }

template = loader.get_template('polls/phasex.html')
context = RequestContext(request,{'id_list':id_list,'country':country,'coords':coords[key],'temp':temp,})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

On template I am trying to access the data:

```
<div style={{'left: '|add:coords.1.0|add:'; top: '|add:coords.1.1|add:';'}} >
<text>{{'left: '|add:coords.1.0|add:'; top: '|add:coords.1.1|add:';'}}</text>
```

actually i should get this when i run:

```
<div style = 'left: 635px; top: 322px'>
```

But i am getting this on the webpage:

```
<div style="left:" 635px;="" top:="" 322px;="">
<text>left: 635px; top: 322px;</text>
</div>
```

I can't understand where's the problem? The text box was for debugging. It's printing properly, but i'm not getting the same inside css styles.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place variables inside quotes, like this:

```
<div style="left:{{ variable }}"></div>
```

And not like this

```
<div style={{ "left: variable" }}></div>
```